# At what point did the Kurama stop sucking Naruto's chakra?

Tags: naruto

While training with Bee, Naruto was warned about the dangers of the Tailed beast chakra mode. Bee mentioned multiple times that Naruto should be careful in how long he maintains the Chakra Mode because while he was using the Nine tails chakra, The Kyuubi was also absorbing his chakra at an equal rate. However, Naruto maintained the tailed beast chakra mode for quite a long time before he fought madara.

[image]

I'm really interested in the exact timeline when the Kyuubi stopped using up Naruto's chakra (So i can better understand just how large Naruto's chakra reserves are). Does anyone know exactly when the Kyuubi stopped taking his chakra back from Naruto?

Comment: I remember the Gyūki noticing Kurma stopped draining Naruto's chakra during their fight with the 5-tails, but I can't recall if it was stated when exactly Kuram stopped doing this

Comment: I think it was when Naruto met his mother(?) When he was fighting against Kurama for Kurama's chakra, his mother's chakra appeared and helped him

Comment: Nah that was how he became able to use the chakra mode @Albert

Answer (score 1):

I think it was somewhere between the conversation when Naruto said that he will take all Kurama's hatred and when Kurama heard him say that he doesn't regret being Jinchuuriki when he fought Tobi and other Jinchuurikis in the forest. Because till then at one point Naruto runs out of the Kuramas chakra so at that time he was still taking it from him. So definitely after real Madara showed up. I think.